# How to modify the contents of text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file contains the following data

```
Repetition,4213-RTN-01-8 Counts BER,Microwave,Huawei-RTN-Alarms,Packet Drop,2938,Normal,Regional Operations,,,
```

and I just need to replace `,` with `,,`

My code is

```
x=open("D:\Work\Robotics\RTN Sheets\pandas.txt","r+")  #open the file with read/write previlage
x.read().replace(",",",,").write() #read the contents and apply the replace action
```

Then I couldn't find a proper way to add this modification for the Text file.

Comment: the `,` is known as a delimiter, if you change it to `,,` it will be as if you are adding empty columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform a file seek to reset the file pointer to 0 after you read the file so that the file content can be replaced rather than appended:

```
with open("D:\Work\Robotics\RTN Sheets\pandas.txt", "r+") as file:
    content = file.read()
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(content.replace(',', ',,'))
```

Comment: thank you it is working now but could you please advise why didn't it work with the following code 

x=open("D:\Work\Robotics\RTN Sheets\pandas.txt","r+")
text=x.read()
x.seek(0)
x.write(text.rereplace(',', ',,'))
x.close

Comment: Glad to be of help. `x.close` is a function, so you should call it by appending parentheses after it: `x.close()`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call .write() method on the string.

Change your second line to `x.write(x.read().replace(",",",,"))`
and also add `x.close()` at the end.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
x = open("text.txt", "r")
a = x.read().replace(",", ",,")
x.close()
x = open("text.txt","w")
x.close()
```

Comment: you have to open file as reading mode then open it again as writing to not append to it.or use f.seek(0) to remove file content before write in it.